# Maintain multiple copies of a database | keep only changed information | Point to existing rows

Tags: postgresql, database-design

My relational database (PostgreSQL) keeps data of college catalog. For example Colleges, Programs, Courses etc. The catalog changes every year, but it's not necessary the content will also change.

This year catalog may have all the data same as the previous year or it may have some changes. I would like to maintain the database based on year.

One way to do is just by making a separate copy every year. But there is a  possibility that only a few things have changed this year. For Example, Just a course name and rest all is same as previous year. In this case, making another copy will not be efficient.

Is there a way to point to the existing database wherever there is no change and if there is change just create only those rows.

Or any other better approach?

Comment: That is literally what a database does.  When you overwrite a row, it only changes that row.  Maybe i'm missing something, but this is the way a database functions.  no need to make additional copies.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Yeah, but I don't want to replace. I wanna keep both the copies. Basically, I want to maintain versions. For example, I have 2 catalog, one is for 2017-2018 and another is for 2016-2017. Now both the catalog has almost same content but just the name of few courses has been changed. Now if I have two separate copies of databases (one for 2017-2018 and another for 2016-2017), it would not be efficient. Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: So add a "AccademicYear" column to each row that specifies which year each record applies to.